# Restricted Scope for GDrive Download

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google Picker to allow users to select and download files (that are re-upload into my own server). All GooglePicker actions are handled in the client side, I just use their own library and their own methods `gapi.client.drive.files.get` and `gapi.client.drive.files.export` to re-upload the files into my server. I got a message from Google saying that scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` will now be restricted.

Considering that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is a MUST to download and export the files I am in a situation I am not sure how to proceed...

1. All the docs talk about Security Auditing for backend, I don't have any backend action with Google. Do I even need the security assessment?
2. I already tried using other scopes like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` but it does not allow me to download the file, and I even get an error saying user gave no permission for the specific file, but I cannot find anywhere how can the user give permissions per-file inside GPicker ui...

So, I was wondering where and how can I get more info on exactly what (and if) I need the security assessment? And if maybe there's a better way of downloading/exporting the files that won't require a restricted scope...